# ng-pattern allows '+' character when regex limits to digits

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, ng-pattern, angularjs-ng-pattern

Am using the regex /^[0-9]+$/ to limit the input of the text box to only accept numbers. It's working fine but when the types something like +124 then also it's not setting the text box as invalid.

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
  <input type="number" ng-model="age" name="age" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/" />
  <h3>Valid Status : {{myForm.age.$valid}}</h3>
</form>
```

Input: 123    Output: myForm.age.$valid - true

Input: -123   Output: myForm.age.$valid - false

Input: +123   Output: myForm.age.$valid - true (shouldn't be true)

https://plnkr.co/edit/3OVE6qiWgJozUb3hyFQ5?p=preview

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why can't it work with type="number" ?? With type="text" browsers let the users type arbitrary characters too.

Comment: Well, regular expressions work with *string* input, regex engines do not allow any other *type* as input. So, only `password`, `text` are usually valid types that will work with a regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the pattern work, you need to set the `type` attribute to `text`. Since you also want to let users type *only* digits into the input field, add an `onkeypress` validation:

```
<input type="text"  onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" ng-model="age" name="age" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/" />
```

Actually, you won't even need the ng-pattern regex then.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use:

```
ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/"
```

Without setting the input type to number (as default it is text and it should work fine).

Here JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ju3b2tu/1/